# ¿Cómo llamo una función desde dentro de otra? PowerShell

Tags: funciones, powershell

Hice un script, funcionaba todo bien hasta que metí algunas partes dentro de unas funciones, me manda error cuando desde una función mando invocar a otra, he estado investigando pero no encuentro por dónde va la solución.

```
function f3(){
...
F1 #error
F2 #erro
}

function F1(){
....
}

function F2(){
...
}
```

El error es:
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'f1'.

Estoy usando powershell 5

Gracias por la ayuda, saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que da error? Porque ejecutando eso que compartiste no genera el error (quitando los puntos, obvio). ¿Si ejecutas las funciones por separado el error desaparece?

Answer (score 1):

Debes de modificar el orden de las funciones. Cuando se ejecute por primera vez el código, leerá *F3* y ésta llama a *F1* y *F2*.
En el momento de llamarlas, no **existen** todavía. 
Una posible solución es crearlas en orden, es decir, crear primero *F1* y *F2*, y posteriormente, *F3* 
 
Ejemplo:

- Si *a* llama a *b* y *c* y éstas están definidas justamente debajo, nos devolverá un errror (siempre en la **primera ejecución**):

[image: Devuelve un error]

- Para solucionarlo, las definimos en el orden en el que van a ser llamadas:
  [image: Una de las posibles soluciones]